# Scrollview does not scroll down to the bottom in Android 8.0

Tags: android, scrollview, android-8.0-oreo

I have this layout and it works fine on all lower versions of Oreo 8.0 . But fails to scroll down the last option "Settings"

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/userLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:background="#4b4949"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/CommonDummy"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_empty_profile" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/farmText"
                    style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameText"
                    style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="19sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/editUserBtn"
                                android:layout_width="32dp"
                                android:layout_height="32dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_menu_right_array"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/CommonDummy"/>-->
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#555555" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/CommonMediumMargin"
            android:background="#4b4949"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/stateText"
                style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:paddingRight="22dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ItemStatus"
                android:textColor="#EDD200" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ItemStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="23.699982dip"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/MenuFarmerBoard"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/CommonXLargeMargin"
                android:background="#ff8686"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuRightFarmerTextHome" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuRightEdit" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buyText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/order_list" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cartText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuLCart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InquiryText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuLInquiry" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PointText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuLPoint" />


        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CommonMediumMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/CommonMediumMargin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#555555" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ProductText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuRightFarmerTextProdcut" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OrderGeneralText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuRightFarmerTextOrderGeneral" />

        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CommonMediumMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/CommonMediumMargin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#555555" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/favoriteText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuRightFarmerTextFavorite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/releaseText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuRightFarmerTextRelease" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expInfoText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuRightFarmerTextExpInfo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/replyText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuRightFarmerTextReply" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reviewText"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:text="@string/MenuLeftTextReview" />

        <!--<TextView
                android:id="@+id/logoutText"
                style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:text="@string/setting_user_info"/>-->

        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CommonMediumMargin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#555555" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Setting"
            style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonMediumRow"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CommonMediumMargin"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_menu_left_more_normal"
            android:text="@string/MenuLeftTextSetting" />

        <!--<TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CommonXLargeMargin"
                android:id="@+id/Terms"
                style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonSmallRow"
                android:textSize="@dimen/CommonMediumText"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:textColor="@color/CommonHint"
                android:text="@string/MenuLeftTextTerms"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ServiceInfo"
                style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonSmallRow"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CommonSmallMargin"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/CommonHint"
                android:textSize="@dimen/CommonMediumText"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:text="@string/MenuLeftTextServiceInfo"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Company"
                style="@style/TextViewMediumDefault"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/CommonSmallRow"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/CommonHint"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/CommonSmallMargin"
                android:textSize="@dimen/CommonMediumText"
                android:paddingLeft="22dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/CommonMediumMargin"
                android:text="@string/MenuLeftTextCompany"/>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Strange because it works on play store version and this file has not been modified. I have tried playing with the margin and padding settings but it still fails. I saw many posts on scrollview not scrolling but since this is only happening on a specific Android version i wonder whats wrong am doing.

Comment: have your tried `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `ScrollView`

Comment: Yup, no luck :(

Comment: @dexter87 try nested scroll view.